# Условие If в лямбда выражении

Tags: c#, linq

Есть конструкция вида `List<Tuple<string, string, int>>` которая используется для формирования строки. Строку формирую так

```
var val = String.Join(",", insert_res.Where(d => d.Item3 == 0)
                .Select(d => "'" + d.Item2 + "'"));
```

Но в зависимости от значения второго строкового параметра мне надо возвращать не в кавычках `"'" + d.Item2 + "'"`, а например в круглых скобках, возможно поместить туда проверку?

Comment: Тернарный оператор `?:` пока никто не отменял.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Есть несколько вариянтов.

Можно использовать тернарный оператор:

```
var val = String.Join(",", insert_res
  .Where(d => d.Item3 == 0)
  .Select(d => condition ? "'" + d.Item2 + "'" : "(" + d.Item2 + ")"));
```

Тоже можно использовать ламбда блок вместо ламбда выражения:

```
var val = String.Join(",", insert_res
  .Where(d => d.Item3 == 0)
  .Select(d => {
    if (condition)
    {
      return "'" + d.Item2 + "'";
    }
    return "(" + d.Item2 + ")";
}));
```

Comment: спасибо, а возможно туда процедуру передавать вместо условия? и как данный подход на производительности отобразится? По сути `Select` это делегат в который предается анонимный метод? Или не так?

Comment: @e1s В блоке можно поставить все, что угодно: процедуры, условия, всё. Да, можно посмотреть документацию: [Enumerable.Select](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb548891(v=vs.100).aspx). То есть, это значение типа `Func<TSource, TResult>`.

Comment: @PeterOlson , сделайте отдельный метод для форматирования строки. Лямбды больше одной строки смотрятся ужасно.